# py2app invalid link to zlib

Tags: python, python-2.7, macports, py2app

I'm trying to package a python program to an app with py2app 0.7.3.
I have one (Mountain Lion) Mac on which I installed the python.org version of Python 2.7.3 and all required modules by using the distributables that were available for them.
However, I also needed a 32-bit version of the app, so on another (Mountain Lion) machine I have set up the same environment (i.e. python + modules) using macports (with i386 for build_arch).

From source, my program runs fine on both machines. However, only the app that is generated on the 64-bit machine works. When trying to run the 32-bit app generated on the macports machine, I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py2app/apptemplate/lib/site.py", line 20, in <module>
    import os
zipimport.ZipImportError: can't decompress data; zlib not available
```

For both apps the same setup.py file was used.

It seems as if the app generated on the macports machine still tries to use the external Python instead of the one that is packaged with it (though it should not be semi-standalone as the system's python was not used). zlib is present in the .app file (and, of course, also outside).

Most other posts I have found about this problem, recommend to alter the sys.path variable in the __boot__.py file that can be found inside the package, but it seems as if my app doesn't even reach that module and crashes beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

I found a, maybe not so elegant, but working solution:

In py2app/__init__.py I set the variable 'Compression' to *False*. This prevents the compression of the site-packages folder to a zipfile. This partly solved the problem as there were still some invalid mach-o error messages afterwards, but by invoking py2app like

```
python setup-mac.py py2app --arch i386
```

the generated app ran fine